# Move files according to a specific pattern in the file name

Tags: unix

I have to copy a list of files having the following pattern in the name: "_my_file" from sub-folders into one main folder. File names appear as the following:

A_my_file.txt
B_my_file.txt
C_my_file.txt

I used the following string but it does not work:

```
find . -name "*_my_file*" -exec mv "{}"./dest_fld \;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add space between `"{}"` and `./dest_fld`:

```
find . -name "*_my_file*" -exec mv "{}" ./dest_fld \;   
#                                      ^
```

It would be better `dest_fld` to be outside the currently directory. Unless, `dest_fld` will be scaned too.